# Managing MODX Resources and Elements from code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, content-management-system, development-environment, modx

I'm importing my plain HTML/CSS website to MODX. I made all of the Elements static, so I can edit them from VS Code + SFTP plugin. But I still have to use MODX Manager to create or delete new Elements.

Is there a convenient way to manage Resources and Elements not switching to the web browser with MODX Manager opened?

It could be a MODX Extra or VS Code plugin watching  `/asset/template` and automatically creating a MODX Template when a new `*.template.tpl` file detected.

Comment: If there isn't such an add-on, do you think creating one makes sence?

Comment: Did not test this, but I believe editing these files directly does not clear the modx cache, where editing the template from within the manager does. This means you will also need to clear the cache directory manually.

Comment: @BramVerstraten, works ok for me, the website updates just after file saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this (untested).
Fill in the full path to the modx directory and templates directory and run the script.

```
<?php
try {
    $modxBasePath = '/full/path/to/modx';
    $templatesPath = '/full/path/to/templates';
    $templatesExtension = 'tpl';

    require_once "$modxBasePath/config.core.php";
    require_once MODX_CORE_PATH.'model/modx/modx.class.php';
    
    $modx = new modX();
    $modx->initialize('mgr');

    if (!is_dir($templatesPath)) {
        throw new Exception("Path $templatesPath is not a directory");
    }

    $files = glob("$templatesPath/*.$templatesExtension");

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $templateName = basename($file, ".$templatesExtension");

        $template = $modx->getObject('modTemplate', ['templatename' => $templateName]);
        if (empty($template)) {
            $template = $modx->newObject('modTemplate', ['templatename' => $templateName]);
        }

        $template->set('content', file_get_contents($file));

        if (!$template->save()) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to save template $templateName.");
        }
    }

    $cm = $modx->getCacheManager();
    $cm->refresh();
    
} catch (Throwable $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I will try creating a plugin with this code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [Gitify](https://github.com/modmore/Gitify) extra is what you need

Comment: Nice extra, but it's not what i'm looking for. It allows to upload Elements' content from DB to git, but it doesn't create Elements itself. Add-on which I need creates DB instance for a new _static_ Element when it detects a new static resource on server.